# Align Scaled Image With Text Centered in Columns

Tags: graphics, lists, columns

Say given a list of items:

```
Item 1: 
Item 2:
Item 3:
Item 4:
```

I want this list to be split into two columns with images aligned on each side of them. Much like a centered bar-graph (If there's a way to do that with a package, that would work too).

```
Image   Item1 Item3   Image
Image   Item2 Item4   Image
```

How might I go about creating the two columns to align to the center of the column?

Comment: Put everything in a table? \begin{tabular}{ll} ... \end{tabular}

Comment: The `listliketab` can do things like that. Take a look at the doc if it suits your needs. Another way of doing things would be to use the `floatrow` package, and a sideways caption; floatrow allows to customise such captions pretty much; in particular, they can be placed at the top-left side of the figure.

Comment: When mixing images and text it generally pays to use \raisebox on the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of achieving your desired output, although it may depend heavily on what your list actually looks like, and how you wish to manage this for (say) a long list of items.

Below I've structured the output using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) so it fills the entire `\linewidth`. Images in columns 1 and 4 are `v`ertically `align`ed to their `t`ops (thanks to [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)), ensuring that large content in columns 2 and 3 remain visually in line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}
    l % Left column image
    >{\raggedleft}X % Left column item
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X % Right column item
    r % Right column image
    @{} }
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} &
  Item 1 &
  Item 3 &
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-c} \\
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-b} &
  Item 2 &
  Item 4 &
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{tabularx}

\clearpage

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}
    l % Left column image
    >{\raggedleft}X % Left column item
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X % Right column item
    r % Right column image
    @{} }
  \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} &
  \lipsum[1] &
  \lipsum[3] &
  \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-c} \\
  \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-b} &
  \lipsum[2] &
  \lipsum[4] &
  \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This list-like structure is maintained manually and doesn't break aross the page boundary.